# How to configure sublime's build system to capture file and line from such error output?

Tags: sublimetext, build-system

If I don't understand wrong, sublime can capture file and line number from error output, by configure the `file_regex` or `line_regex`.

I have such error output:

```
  main.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>   file:///Users/freewind/dev/workspace/RythmDart/test/test_grammar.dart 135:19
```

How to configure the build file?

I tried:

```
"line_regex": "([\\w/:\\-_]*) (\\d*):(\\d*)",
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: As an aside - note that there is a SublimeText2 package for Dart - https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-sublime-bundle.  However, their build system is complicated and I didn't have much luck with that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
    "file_regex": ".*file:\/\/\/(.*):([0-9]*):[0-9]*",
```

Note that:

- this uses a file_regex instead of line_regex
- I am using Sublime Text 2
- I am running dart.exe on Windows

I am running a simple dart command line program and get output like this:

```
Hello world

Unhandled exception:
exception
#0      main (file:///C:/src_test/dart/dart_test.dart:4:3)
```

Here is my test program:

```
void main() {
  print("Hello world\n");
  throw 'exception';
}
```

---

edit:

for mac, it should be:

```
"file_regex": ".*file:\/\/(.*):([0-9]*):[0-9]*",
```

Notice there are only two `\/`s after `file:`, or sublime will try to find a file with wrong path, e.g.

> ~/dev/dart/myproject/Users/home/freewind/dev/dart/myproject/test.dart

If I use two `\/`, it will be correct:

> /Users/home/freewind/dev/dart/myproject/test.dart